# How do I clear the focus on an editext? Other StackOverflow posts haven't helped much

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I've looked at other StackOverflow posts, but many of them don't work, or the comments say that they don't work. I'm wondering how I can clear the focus on an edittext. I was hoping that when I close the keyboard, it would also lose focus, but this didn't happen.

Because of this, whenever someone exits the app and goes back in *(with the app running in the background)* the regular keyboard shows up, even though it's not supposed to. I have a whole system in place for managing the keyboard.

**Code for showing/closing keyboard**

```java
private void closeEmojiKeyboard()
    {
        ivEmoji.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ivKeyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        showKeyboard(etMessage);
        llEmojiKeyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void showKeyboard(EditText view)
    {
        view.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
```

**Code for hiding keyboard when someone opens the emoji keyboard**

```java
ivEmoji.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ivKeyboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        hideKeyboard(etMessage);
        llEmojiKeyboard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**And the code that hides the emoji keyboard when clicking the editext**

```java
llEmojiKeyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                showKeyboard(etMessage);
                ivEmoji.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ivKeyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rvMessages.scrollToPosition(messagesList.size()-1);
```

Can anybody share some code with me that could help clear focus on my edittext? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can

ex 1.

```
 editText.clearFocus()
```

ex 2.

```
EditText et = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.my_name);
 et.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL); // setCursorVisible(false);
```